# PHP SQL GET and OR?

Tags: php, sql, get

For use with SQL query.

Is it possible to pass an OR through GET?

```
variable=value OR othervalue
```

Or is it just easier to define multiple variables and then make the SQL filter from the multiple variables.

Comment: You could send the values as an array, ?value[]=variable&value[]=variable2 (properly urlencoded ofcourse)

Comment: What would you like to achieve exactly?
You could just pass a string with all the values joined, something like ?id_list=1,2,3 and then do a parsing, or, depending on your database, use ANY compare.

Comment: i think you dont know how exactly sql injection works but yes it wont do any harm

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. It was more of a question to see if anyone knows of an obscure easy method.
Hank- Unfortunately this method will not work with my existing code without a massive rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your `GET` parameters like so:

```
script.php?variable[]=happy&variable[]=sad
```

In your script, these will be stored in `$_GET[variable]` as an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => happy
    [1] => sad
)
```

You can then bind the parameters and send your statement (haven't tested):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$type = '';

$query = 'SELECT column FROM bubbles WHERE variable IN (';

for($i = 0; $i < count($_GET[variable]); $i++) {
   $query .= '?';
   $type .= 's';
   if($i+1 < count($_GET[variable])) $query .= ', ';
}

$query .= ')';

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);

call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($stmt, $type), $_GET[variable])); 

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: +1: I wish I could upvote twice, because this is both a solid answer AND it implicitly addresses injection concerns.

Comment: Please... NEVER EVER use unquoted array keys. It relies on a horrible PHP mis-feature (stringifying undefined constants) and results in an E_NOTICE everytime you do it.